# Importing blog failed to download attachments from older (still online) blog

Tags: uploads, media, import, export, server

I was trying to clone one blog to another using the import/export functionality of WordPress. I had selected to export everything on the original blog, and *Download attachments* on the clone.

However, I received an error message for each image of the source, saying that the download failed.

The images actually show up, both in the editor and on the site. Obviously both blogs are live.

It is possible to upload arbitrary images to the blog's media library (but I had to increase the file size in nginx manually for some reason).

**What is the problem and how can I solve it?**

Older blog URL: [keliom.com](http://keliom.com) 
Newer blog URL: [jancorazza.com](http://jancorazza.com) 
Server: nginx 
OS: Ubuntu 14.04 
[Export file](http://www.sendspace.com/file/b55wc9)

Comment: What was/is error message verbatim?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do a straight copy of the wp-content/uploads/ folder. You may have to do a find/replace on the original export file to change file URLs if they were absolute file paths.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the issue was that the export file I tried to use had https-based URLs for some reason, and that downloading the media through https somehow failed. Most likely because, when switching VPS', I moved some certificates or something, making my old blog's SSL invalid. This is highly speculative though.

I exported it once again with http-based URLs, and there were no errors.

I can see the pictures in my media library, **but the pictures in my actual posts all link to my old blog**, for some reason. This is on the edge of acceptability, so I'm gonna roll with it and just manually edit the images (since I'm switching gallery plugins I think I'd have to do it anyway).